# Query to insert or update n column from Parent table into 2 column of history table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, audit-trail

i need PHP-MYSQL Query ( code ) for History table: I know what i have to do and how - but not getting how to write mysql query for it and same for listing in php page . below is what i have think and want to implement.

i have Product table as : **product_table**

```
id | cat_id   | Subcat |productname | weight    | assigned_to  | status_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |   11     |   2    |     P1     | 5.8       |        8     |   1
2  |   12     |   3    |     P2     | 6.7       |        27    |   2
```

they are main more coloumn under product_table such add_date , update_date ..etc

Now if i Insert or Update my **Product table(product_table)** then its each record whether its new (insert) or update record , its should get inserted/update in my **History Table(history_table)** as :

*Below is what when **New Value is Insert in product_table**  and same goes **under history table** as below :*

```
id | pid   |  cat_id   | sub_cat   | old_value    |  new_value   | filed_name     | date_m  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  1    |   11      |   2       |     0        |     P1       |   productname  | 2014-01-17 05:05:21
2  |  1    |   11      |   2       |     0        |     5.8      |   weight       | 2014-01-17 05:05:21
3  |  1    |   11      |   2       |     0        |     8        |   assigned to  | 2014-01-17 05:05:21
4  |  1    |   11      |   2       |     0        |     1        |   status       | 2014-01-17 05:05:21
```

Now when under product table : **record 1 is update** then same goes under history table AS below :

```
id | pid   |  cat_id   | sub_cat   | old_value    |  new_value   | field_name    |  date_m 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  1    |   11      |   2       |     P1       |     P2       |   productname |  2014-01-18 03:05:22
2  |  1    |   11      |   2       |     5.8      |     5.4      |   weight      |  2014-01-18 03:05:22
3  |  1    |   11      |   2       |     8        |     7        |   assigned to |  2014-01-18 03:05:22
4  |  1    |   11      |   2       |     1        |     4        |   status      |  2014-01-18 03:05:22
```

hence when i see my **Product Page of id : 1** history then it will look as below :

```
     Date            | User  |     field_name       |  Change
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-01-17 05:05:21  | admin |     productname      |       =>  P1
2014-01-17 05:05:21  | admin |     weight           |       =>  5.8
2014-01-17 05:05:21  | admin |     assigned to      |       =>  8
2014-01-17 05:05:21  | admin |     status           |       =>  1 

2014-01-18 03:05:22  | admin |     productname      |  P1   =>  P2
2014-01-18 03:05:22  | admin |     weight           |  5.8  =>  5.4
2014-01-18 03:05:22  | admin |     assigned to      |  8    =>  7 
2014-01-18 03:05:22  | admin |     status           |  1    =>  4
```

Hence this is what i am thinking to implement but not getting what code(mysql) should be written while inserting and updating , so that some (which i want to ) Column in product_table should be insert/update in 2 column of history_table and reset as coloumn wise as define above. AND how i can display on my product page as of history.

Answer (score 0):

Create `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` and `AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER` on table `product_table`.

Check this links

1. [**CREATE TRIGGER SYNTAX**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html)
2. [**CREATE TRIGGER FOR HISTORY TABLE**](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/)

Comment: @ Saharsh bhai , first of all thanks for your reply.. dear i have gone through above link already but as said i want both old and new value in my history table .. hence i am not getting how to write BEFORE_UPDATE AND AFTER_UPDATE TIGGER together , as before update i will get my old value and after update i will get my new value...also how i can update or insert my 4 column(productname,weight,assigned_to,status_id) value from product_table  into  2 column(old_vale,new_value) of history_table and reset coloumn as in..please see above structure